# Modifying a Function Later

Tags: python

I have the function:

```
def f(a):
    x = 0

    for i in a:
        if i > 0:
            x += 1


    print(x)

list = [Some Numbers]

f(list)
```

Then I needed the same function but with a small change inside the if statement as shown:

```
def f(a):
    x = 0

    for i in a:
        if i > 0:
            x += 2


    print(x)

list2 = [Some Numbers]

f(list2)
```

I want a way to make the same modification but without writing the same whole function again, So that defining in python will be useful as it had to be in the first place.

Comment: I don't think that modification should be inside the function. What you have is a function that counts positive numbers in a list. You should return rather than printing, then you can just double it outside the function. You can read up on functions here: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this. when you need the +1 then just call `f(your_input)` but when you need the +2 use it like this `f(your_input, added=2)`:

```
def f(a, added=1):
    x = 0

    for i in a:
        if i > 0:
            x += added
```